# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException is getting randomly

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver, selenium-server

selenium 2.53.0 
and firefox 45

all the test cases were working working fine but suddenly there are generating Randomly a exception as shown below

can somebody please help in solving this problem ?

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'USBLRPRPUJAR8', ip: '172.16.20.43', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: e5da75ec-52d5-4cba-b8b8-5fd124aaefd3
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:899)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
    at com.bersin.bersinone.pages.BersinOnePage.waitforBersinonepageload(BersinOnePage.java:35)
    at com.bersin.test.utils.LoginUser.BosucessfullLogin(LoginUser.java:42)
    at com.bersin.bersinone.searchtestcases.TC001_Empty_Research_Search.perfromLogin(TC001_Empty_Research_Search.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1519; received: 0
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:200)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy.streamClosed(ResponseEntityProxy.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.createResponse(ApacheHttpClient.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:380)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 36 more

SKIPPED: perfromEmptySearch
java.lang.Throwable: Method TC001_Empty_Research_Search.perfromEmptySearch()[pri:2, instance:com.bersin.bersinone.searchtestcases.TC001_Empty_Research_Search@520a3426] depends on not successfully finished methods
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1033)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

SKIPPED: checkdefaultsortoption
java.lang.Throwable: Method TC001_Empty_Research_Search.checkdefaultsortoption()[pri:3, instance:com.bersin.bersinone.searchtestcases.TC001_Empty_Research_Search@520a3426] depends on not successfully finished methods
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1033)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium abotring with "UnreachableBrowserException/Address already in use" occurring on one computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261602/selenium-abotring-with-unreachablebrowserexception-address-already-in-use-occu)

Comment: No that's not relevant solution for this problem as user on that thread had problem with ports on windows XP as the error was caused by Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect but in my case error is Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1519; received: 0

Comment: Sounds like you have network problems and the server you are talking to is closing the connection.  There really isn't enough information here to work out what the cause is.